# Match names from one table with names from other

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a table

| CID | FirstName | LastName | Loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Brad | Shaw | ASD |
| 234 | Chad | Reed | SES |
| 345 | Bryan | Miles | WED |
| 456 | Mr Bradley | Knight | ASD |
| 567 | Doctor Chadwick | Prince | WED |
| 678 | Mrs Bryana | Yang | SES |
| 789 | Arty-stry | Blue | POR |

Another table

| FirstName |
| --- |
| Bryan |
| Ben |
| Brad |
| Chad |

I wish to have a result matching all the names from 2nd table with names in 1st table, no matter if names in 2nd table form sort of substrings of 1st table.

| CID | FirstName | LastName | Loc | TABLE2_MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Brad | Shaw | ASD | Brad |
| 234 | Chad | Reed | SES | Chad |
| 345 | Bryan | Miles | WED | Bryan |
| 456 | Mr Bradley | Knight | ASD | Brad |
| 567 | Doctor Chadwick | Prince | WED | Chad |
| 678 | Mrs Bryana | Yang | SES | Bryan |
| 789 | Arty-stry | Blue | POR | No_match |

I have thousands of names and I need to find a better way of doing this, currently I am trying to do IN statement but that matches exact names, where as I want substrings to match as well. I hope this is clear. Happy to give more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all outer joins where `FirstName` from table1 is `like` table2's `FirstName` wrapped in '%' :

```
select
  a.CID,
  a.FirstName,
  a.LastName,
  a.Loc,
  coalesce(b.FirstName, 'No_match') as TABLE2_MATCH
from table1 a
left join table2 b on lower(a.FirstName) like '%' || lower(b.FirstName) || '%'
```

String X being a substring of string Y can be expressed as `Y like '%X%'`.
Calls to `lower()` make it case insensitive, although see if it still works if you remove calls to `lower()`.

Comment: No `lower` needed in Teradata as these columns are probably defined as `not casepecific`. And `concat` was implemented only recently, Standard SQL `'%' || b.FirstName || '%')` will work, too.

Comment: simple neat and easy to understand. Thanks heaps. This will help me clean up other bunch of tables as well.